# Еhe function does not replace array elements with elements of another array by condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Good afternoon. I need to make a function that will take two arrays and monitor if the date of the element of the first array is equal to the date of the element of the second array, then the element of the first array should be replaced by the element of the second array, if the dates are not equal, then the element of the first array will be replaced by an empty object.
For example, there are two arrays.

```
let array1 = [
    {
        date: '2020-04-20',
        groups: ['apple', 'banana'],
        teachers: ['potate', 'carrot'],
    },
    {
        date: '2020-04-21',
        groups: [],
        teachers: [],
    },
    {
        date: '2020-04-22',
        groups: ['tomato', 'peach'],
        teachers: ['orange', 'cucumber'],
    },
];
let array2 = [
    {
        date: '2020-04-20',
        groups: ['car', 'plane'],
        teachers: ['drive', 'fly'],
    },
    {
        date: '2020-04-21',
        groups: ['lalal', 'kykyky'],
        teachers: ['lalal', 'kykyky'],
    }
];
```

The two arrays that are above are accepted by the function, and the function should return such an array:

```
let expectResult = [
    {
        date: '2020-04-20',
        groups: ['car', 'plane'],
        teachers: ['drive', 'fly'],
    },
    {
        date: '2020-04-21',
        groups: ['lalal', 'kykyky'],
        teachers: ['lalal', 'kykyky'],
    }
    {
        date: '2020-04-22',
        groups: [],
        teachers: [],
    },
]
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

This is what I did myself:

```
let payload = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < payload.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < combineArrays.length; j++) {
            if (payload[i].date === combineArrays[j].date) {
                console.log(i, j);
                finalArray.splice(i - 1, 1, combineArrays[j]);
            } else {
                finalArray.splice(i - 1, 1,{
                    date: payload[i].date,
                    groups: [],
                    teachers: [],
                    time: [],
                    type: [],
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let array1=[{date:"2020-04-20",groups:["apple","banana"],teachers:["potate","carrot"]},{date:"2020-04-21",groups:[],teachers:[]},{date:"2020-04-22",groups:["tomato","peach"],teachers:["orange","cucumber"]}],array2=[{date:"2020-04-20",groups:["car","plane"],teachers:["drive","fly"]},{date:"2020-04-21",groups:["lalal","kykyky"],teachers:["lalal","kykyky"]}];

let tempEl
let result = array1.map(el1 => {
    tempEl = array2.find(el2 => el2.date == el1.date)
    if(!tempEl){
        return {date: el1.date, groups: [], teachers: []}
    }else{
        return tempEl
    }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

1. Compare array elements by index

   - I believe your errors are coming out of different array sizes.
   - i.e. you're trying to access array[index] out of bounds
   - so you need to check whether the array at index in B is null / undefined
2. Do what you need to do (replace the console.log with resetting to an empty object per your requirements)

```js
// A and B are array 1 and 2 respectively, and i is the index

for (i in A) {
  if (B[i] != null) { // -> this is the check you're missing
    if (A[i].date != B[i].date) {
      console.log(A[i].date); // -> here you do what you need
    }
  }
}
```

Also, note this assumes elements are also in exact order, and match up perfectly. In case they're not, using `find` as per symlink's answer is better.

Comment: I added in my question what I did